# FFMPEG to add audio to video at specific intervals

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a audio of 2 mints . How to add it to a longer video of say 10 mints at some specific intervals using ffmpeg. Say after 2 mints of the audio play there is a 1 minute gap and then it plays again . I tried to add it but it plays only once at the start of the video

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit only the audio track to line it up to the video times. You need [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/download/) or similar DAW app.

```
ffmpeg -i your_file.mkv -vn audio.wav && ffmpeg -i your_file.mkv -an -c copy video.mkv
```

Now you have the streams separated.  Open `audio.wav` with Audacity.  I have inserted 60 seconds of silence at the 30 second marker in this example:

[image: Audacity example]

This is pretty much all it takes.  Add time where needed, cut/paste etc.  Under 'Edit', there is also 'silence audio', to overwrite existing audio with silence. It can be handy. Then, export to WAV `audio_new.wav`. Re-encode the audio back to `.m4a`.

```
ffmpeg -i audio_new.wav audio_new.m4a
```

Now recombine your audio and video:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i audio_new.m4a -c copy video_new.mkv
```

That should do it.

Comment: Any question that requires an answer about interactive use of non-programming-specific tools is almost certainly categorically off-topic here -- and note that [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) has a section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, which therein advises answering only questions that fit within the Help Center's topic guidelines.